Terraform deployment GCE default service account error
When trying to deploy a project via terraform I’m getting the bellow issue:
Error: Error when reading or editing GCE default service account: googleapi: Error 401: Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.
│ Details:
│ [
│   {
│     "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
│     "metadatas": {
│       "method": "compute.v1.ProjectsService.Get",
│       "service": "compute.googleapis.com"
│     },
│     "reason": "ACCESS_TOKEN_TYPE_UNSUPPORTED"
│   }
│ ]
│
│ More details:
│ Reason: authError, Message: Invalid Credentials
│
│
│   with data.google_compute_default_service_account.default,
│   on iam.tf line 7, in data "google_compute_default_service_account" "default":
│    7: data "google_compute_default_service_account" "default" {

Ihave checked the default GCE account and initially it was missing a key so i created it but without success. The issue happens when I try to add rights to the account.
in the iam.tf file I define the account as:
data "google_compute_default_service_account" "default" {
  project = var.project_id
}

Is there a way that I can change the default service account in the terraform iam file with a preset account? Or is there a different solution I could try?

This just sounds like your terraform command is not being ran with valid credentials towards google, how are you authenticating your terraform commands?

@ Rocco Did you have time to check my answer? It helped you to solve your problem? If yes,could you please have a look at this doc and accordingly proceed.

The error message you are facing is due to the terraform attempting to access Google cloud services with a invalid or unsupported authentication.
To resolve your issue set OAuth Token for cloud shell or  you need to use a definite service Account key :
As per this Hashicorp document

If you are using cloud shell First, authenticate with GCP. The easiest
way to do this is to run gcloud auth application-default login, if
you already have gcloud installed. If you don't already have it, you
can install it from here.
You can use a Google Cloud Service Account with terraform. From the
service account key page in the Cloud Console choose an existing
account, or create a new one. Next, download the JSON key file. Name
it something you can remember, and store it somewhere secure on your
machine.
Note: Currently the only supported service account credentials are credentials downloaded from Cloud Console or generated by gcloud.
You supply the key to Terraform using the environment variable
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS, setting the value to the location of
the file. export
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS={{path}}


This helps to use service accounts for authentication. instead of the default GCE service account.
